# Elasticsearch reindex ignores mapping param dynamic false

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to implement some kind of migration for mapping changes. So my problem is I want to use reindex if for some reason my new mapping doesn't work with my current data (e.g. types changed). If a field has been removed I do the following:

- create a new index with the new mapping (where the removed field is not included)
- reindex my current index in the newly created index
- delete old index and set alias to new index

The dynamic mapping for this type is set to false so I thought the removed field will just be ignored when the data is reindexed into the new index with the new mapping. So my problem is the field just gets copied into the new index although there is no mapping defined for this one. As described in the documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/dynamic.html) I thought the field without any mapping would be ignored.

On the other hand a dynamic mapping set to strict would fail.

Am I missing something or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do other way,specify the fields in the source for which you defined mapping.

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "old index",
    "_source": ["field1", "field2","field3"]
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new index"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah i know about this one, but the implementation doing this would be a little bit more. Just thought it would work out of the box using reindex with a new mapping and dynamic false.